# Jenkins: How can I populate parameters from database to parameterized job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I need to pull values from database and show parameters as dropdown in Jenkins parameterized job. Is there any available plugin to achieve this?

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plug-in to pull values from database and show parameters as dropdown in Jenkins parameterized job.

**LINK:**

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in

We have to write groovy script to pull values from database and click on above link for more details.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how you did this?

Comment: Yes, can you explain that please ?

Comment: Link is dead
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in

Comment: There is no any refference on how to fetch from database